# Mechanics of fanatic badge

Tags: support, badges

When it comes to the fanatic or any of the other similar badges does it require accessing a certain page or a certain kind of access method, eg via browser not RSS? Just want to be sure the way I'm checking in doesn't pose a problem the next time I get started trying to get it.

Comment: I bet you're trying to figure out a way to script this aren't you? =P

Comment: If you're actually a fanatic, you'll get this badge without even noticing.  If you take a day off, you're not really a fanatic.

Comment: Not trying to script it. Jut wanting to understand how it works. I don't use the browser on my phone often.

Comment: If it helps, I got mine while on holiday in Morocco using my iPhone over the local free wireless.  The iPhone definitely counts.

Answer (score 6):

You must access the site via either the full web experience, or the mobile site. But: the front page is not enough. What is enough? [Who knows](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions) (see the Fanatic badge. This is to avoid gaming via scripts).

RSS etc doesn't count because there's no relationship between the RSS feed and your user account.

Comment: Generally  voting on a few questions and/or asking/answering/commenting should guarantee you credit for a "visit" -- basically *legitimately use the site* and you'll almost certainly get credit for the day :)

Comment: In the past it was enough to simply have the [Notifier Chrome Extension](http://stackapps.com/questions/1941/notifier-chrome-extension).  Whatever it did managed to count.  All you had to do was start your browser.  I think it has been changed though.